# gerrit ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/dev (branch dev not found) error: failed to push some refs to 'project'

Tags: git, gerrit, git-rebase

I have a master branch and dev branch, i also confirmed by checking by git-branch.

In my master branch there is current working version of the code.

I created new branch dev and then rebased to dev branch

Now I have the same files in master and dev branch and i planned to work on dev branch. the reason doing like this pushing to dev branch can be done without reviews and pushing to master needs review.

I havent done any changes in dev branch as of now but wanted to push this to dev branch as everyone can see this dev branch . then i get error like (this below error came when i did git push origin dev)

```
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (7/7)                                                                                     
remote: error: branch refs/heads/dev:                                                                                       
remote: You need 'Create' rights to create new references.                                                              
remote: User: aravmadd                                                                                                  
remote: Contact an administrator to fix the permissions                                                                 
remote: Processing changes: refs: 1, done       
    
gerrit ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/dev (branch dev not found) error: failed to push some refs to 'project'
```

But i have all rights required, except that i didnt create this repository

when i tried to use git push origin HEAD:refs/for/dev then i get error like

```
 ! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/dev (branch dev not found)
```

What i did was i created new branch dev and rebased

```
git checkout dev
git rebase master dev

$ git status
On branch dev
nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ ls
CMakeLists.txt  doc/  extern/  modules/  Readme.md  README.txt  test/
```

then i can see the same files in master and dev branch.

for your information, master branch is properly reviewed.

Then i decided this to push since everything i changed was in my localpc.

Am i doing something wrong??.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The "dev" branch doesn't exit on Gerrit, you just created it locally in your machine.
2. When you pushed to "refs/heads/dev" you tried to create the "dev" branch on Gerrit but you don't have permission to create branches. You need to have "Create Reference" permission on "refs/*".
3. It's not possible to push to "refs/for/dev" (create a review on Gerrit) because the "dev" branch doesn't exist in Gerrit (see 1. above).